# Show that a sequence $\{a_n\}$ is bounded iff there is an interval $[c, d]$ such that $\{a_n\}$ is a sequence in $[c,d]$

Tags: real-analysis

Since this is an iff proof, I know it must go in two directions. I think I understand the reverse direction, by saying that if there is an interval $[c,d]$ with sequence $\{a_n\}$ in $[c,d]$, then for all $x$ in $\{a_n\}$, we have $d \geq x$ and $c \leq x$, so that $d$ is an upper bound and $c$ is a lower bound. Since $\{a_n\}$ has an upper and a lower bound, it is bounded.

First, is that correct? Second, how would you show the other direction?

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, yes, I agree with your logic.

For the second part, here is what I think:

Suppose $a_{n}$ is bounded.  Then $\exists M > 0$ such that $|a_{n}| \leq M$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  Then $-M \leq a_{n} \leq M$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  But this implies $a_{n} \in [-M, M]$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, which is what we wanted to prove.